# Digital signature with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, digital-signature

I am using the MEAN stack and I would like to implement a digital signature for employees with a form but I cannot find any library or tutorial on this topic.

Has anyone done this? What would be the right approach to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out ngSignaturePad. It uses SignaturePad jQuery plugin.

https://github.com/ecentinela/ng-signature-pad

Answer (score 6):

Thank you for the question vonwolf! I found another solution check this:

https://github.com/legalthings/angular-signature

However, I tried to implement a simple example using the above, but I see errors in the console which I cannot resolve. I did the same ng-signature-pad, and it is working just fine without any error.

[Simple example using angular-signature Control](http://plnkr.co/edit/TvpmtxjulMFHtTCR6SnZ?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Sample angular-singature</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/legalthings/angular-signature/master/src/signature.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/szimek/signature_pad/master/signature_pad.js"></script>
  <style>
    .nowrap {
      white-space:pre-wrap;
      word-wrap:break-word;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body ng-app='app' ng-controller='SignModalCtrl'>
  <h1>Angular Signature Sample</h1>
  <signature-pad accept="accept" clear="clear" height="220" width="568"></signature-pad>
  <button ng-click="clear()">Clear signature</button>
  <button ng-click="doAccept()">Sign</button>
  <pre class='nowrap' ng-bind="accept().dataUrl"></pre>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', [
      'signature',
    ]);
    app.controller('SignModalCtrl', [
      '$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.doAccept = function () {
          var signature = $scope.accept();
          console.log('doAccpet', signature)
        }
        $scope.done = function() {
          var signature = $scope.accept();

          if (signature.isEmpty) {
            $modalInstance.dismiss();
          } else {
            $modalInstance.close(signature.dataUrl);
          }
        };
      }
    ]);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[And, here is the other simple example using ng-signature-pad](http://plnkr.co/edit/vohTMk?p=preview)

Also, you can find other solutions:

https://www.sitepoint.com/4-jquery-digital-signature-plugins/

Tarek

Comment: Hi , I have a question.

Comment: How can we set a default data URL ? like when a page is loaded it will show a signature example based on for example this data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAjgAAADcCAYAAAB9P9tLAAAVi0lEQVR4Xu3deaw0WVkH4B8GIaCDiorAjBEwOAFRjKIIiVGiUVHHxA1FEhVZ1MEFGJQgiYhxGVDEIGBAhEFhXAYEBxUlY+APXFlMNGA0DoiCKKOyGjYV88bqWLa3v9t9v+57b73nOQmZ4fv6VvX7vEXuj6pT59wsBgECBAgQIECgmcDNmtWjHAIECBAgQIBABBwXAQECBAgQINBOQMBp11IFESBAgAABAgKOa4AAAQIECBBoJyDgtGupgggQIECAAAEBxzVAgAABAgQItBMQcNq1VEEECBAgQICAgOMaIECAAAECBNoJCD

Comment: Cause i am planning on saving the data url to db and then retrieved it show the signature